how does gore-tex block liquid water
All explanations for how Gore-Tex works say that it has microscopic pores that are larger than water molecules in the damp phase, but smaller than water droplets. This way it explains why raincoats with Gore-Tex keep the rain out while allowing your sweat to "breathe" through the raincoat. What I don't understand are:
Q1. Why can't water molecules from raindrops pass the membrane one at a time?
Q2. How can a gaseous water molecule, from your sweat, pass through the membrane while the other side is saturated with rain water?
Now that I am formulating these questions, I am wondering if this may be related to phase changes. Q1 would perhaps involve vaporization, and Q2 condensation, and I remember from school that vaporization of water needs a lot of energy, and condensation releases that same amount of energy.
Then there is another strange feature. Gore-Tex raincoats also need a DWR, a Durable Water Repellent treatment to keep the outside from beeing soaked.
Q3. It seems to me that the task of the membrane and dwr is the same: keep liquid out but allow damp to pass through
Please help me to understand Gore-Tex on a more technical level than the sales pitch by outdoor experts.

The membrane is not magic. If it is 100% humidity outside then it will be 100% humidity inside your jacket too. Still, water drops don’t come through.

@JonCuster but then during rain your sweat cannot evaporate and escape through the raincoat, but will condensate on the inside of the raincoat and make you miserably wet

And that does happen. While the membrane is very hydrophobic, outer layers are not (so much) and if being soaked by water, they suppress diffusion of vapor to free air.

@Roland - if it is 100% relative humidity, yup. There is no magic. However, having lived in the era of rubber-coated rain jackets, any breathing helps much of the time.

I see serious comments and an answer, so am curious why someone downvotes this question

Thanks to the other answer and comments, and the YouTube links provided, I am understanding more of Gore-Tex.
This material is hydrophobic because it is teflon. The pores are no obstacle for the tiny water molecules in the gas phase. The reason liquid water can't get through the pores is the large "contact angle" between the solid teflon and the liquid water. One of the YouTube links show that the liquid can be sucked up or pushed back in a capillary tube depending on contact angle. The pores in Gore-Tex are just like capillaries. There is no need to assume the forming of droplets and their radius. Its just a matter of contact angle.
What I assume is that water damp molecules can go through the pores from inside to outside even if the outside is soaking wet. When such water molecule goes through the pore and meets the liquid water, it will just be absorbed by the liquid, also called condensation, which is an exothermic process.
There is no reason to assume that the wet side consists of water droplets with water vapor of a certain humidity percentage in between. But if you do, you should also estimate how many pores are covered by a liquid drop, and how many by water vapor.
From a non-tech, but practical viewpoint, I don't know if it is useful to want to transfer vapor (sweat) from inside to the outside of the jacket during rain. The advantage of a Gore-Tex jacket is that it is breathable in dry weather and waterproof in rain. During rain there is no sun, and it is much cooler, so we produce much less sweat.
I took an old jacket apart, and found that the membrane is NOT a exceedingly thin layer, but just a sheet of white material applied to the outer fabric of the jacket. The story of Gore-Tex is taking a sheet of teflon and expand it a few hundred percent, so the sheet sure is thin, but still comparable to, say, a plastic grocery bag. Some bags are sturdy, others are quite thin and can only be used once or twice before falling apart.
The working of Gore-Tex is in the pores, not necessarily the thinness. Of course a very thick layer won't work better, and will be more expensive.
The problem with Gore-Tex is, if course, that this membrane layer will get damaged after a while. Especially if you, like me, carry a bag on a shoulder strap, or, even worse, a backpack, loaded with a lot of heavy crap like laptop computers etc.
On the taken apart jacket I found lots of danaged spots, little cracks and holes in the membrane layer. Normally you can't check for such damage because of extra layers in the jacket that hide the membrane from view.
I do daily biking and live in a "wet" country, the Netherlands, but actually the number of days that I bike through rain is pretty low. So I really love my expensive breathable jacket, but get annoyed when the jacket seems to leak in the rain. Now my policy is to buy a cheap breathable jacket but replace it earlier.
As for the camera, just note if the pockets are inside or outside of the waterproof parts before using it for carrying sensitive objects.
As for the DWR, for me this is still a mystery. Perhaps a sales ploy to sell extra stuff to clean, maintain and reactivate it. I have never done any maintenance on my breathable jackets and believe that the leaks that made me buy a new jacket came from wear and tear of the membrane inside the jacket.

GORE-TEX is not merely rabidly hydrophobic, because it's made of PTFE, but it is also perforated. Though termed "microporous", the perforations are billions of times larger than that of water vapor molecules, which pass freely through the holes. Yes, humidity inside and outside would be the same.
However, water droplets cohere. If they cohere more to themselves than they adehere to a surface, they form droplets. These droplets are too large to pass through the GORE-TEX interlayer.
Why not make the entire garment of GORE-TEX?

The material is exceedingly thin and fragile.
Any grease or other surface contminant would plug the holes.

Since the GORE-TEX must be protected, the outer layer of the garment still needs water protection, or water will pool between the outer layer and the GORE-TEX middle layer. That happened to me on a long hike in the rain -- though liquid water did not penetrate to the inside of the cagoule, pockets and other untreated areas let the rain penetrate and stay inside. slosh, slosh, slosh This did not improve the camera I had in a pocket.

ok, so humidity inside and outside are equal when its not raining, and dampness from sweat will transfer through the jacket. When raining, rainwater will form large drops that cannot pass the membrane. Between the drops will be damp of 100% humidity, so sweat cannot go out, right?

@Roland, it is not in equilibrium. There may be water droplets covering part of the surface, yet humidity might not be 100% -- droplets might even evaporate, since the fabric is warmed by body.
